# Having a Problem After Installing Mac-osx Theme and setting it up With Cairo dock

Tags: package-management, dpkg, sudo

When I enter `sudo apt-get upgrade`, this message shows up:

```
dpkg: error: cannot scan updates directory `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/': No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any Help ?!

Answer (score 0):

This *may* work.

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail  
sudo apt-get update
```

It may also not. You also need to check your file system for errors, and make sure your only using repos that are for your version of Ubuntu.

I would start with the above commands, then if that still doesn't work,  have a look [here](http://uug.byu.edu/pipermail/uug-list/2009-October/002923.html) for restoring your apt database.

You can also try **(very dangerous)**

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/updates /root/  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/updates    
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

Assuming you're back on track you can then remove the copy of updates in `/root/updates`